# Preprocessor magic to complete typename in template

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I have a bunch of user-defined structs; let's call them A, B and C.

I can't modify them and I need to add logging capabilities; so I've added my own log versions of these structures to help with that.
Let's call them A_Log, B_Log and C_Log.

I'm creating a template StateLogger class with a member function called `LogState(const T *ptr)` where `T` is intended to be A, B or C.

```
template <typename T>
class StateLogger {
    public:
    void LogState(const T *ptr);

    private:
    std::vector<T> requests;
};
```

In this function, I intend to construct the A_Log/B_Log/C_Log structure.

```
template<typename T>
void StateLogger<T>::LogState(const T *ptr) {
    ...
    VOODOO myLog = VOODOO(ptr);

}
```

I'm wondering if I can use some preprocessor magic to append `_Log` to `T` in `VOODOO`.
So, if I used `StateLogger<A>::LogState(a_ptr)`
I'd like the compiler to generate `A_Log` instead of `Voodoo`.

I realize I can use template specialization to get around this, but I was curious about this.

Comment: No preprocessor hacks for this, please!

Comment: You can't use the preprocessor here as templates are instantiated only after the preprocessor has already run. I.e. you cannot use the type name used to instantiate the template in the preprocessor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <class T> struct logger_type;
template <> struct logger_type<A> {
    typedef A_Log type;
};
```

etc.

With that, whenever you need the logger, just use `typename logger_type<T>::type`.

Comment: you could then use preprocessor magic on top of this if you want: foreach type T, specialize logger_type for T.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a way without having to typedef every structure.

Comment: @Raja - yup, I answered without reading the full question. But in general, that kind of thing can't be done with the preprocessor, so it's usually done with "traits", of which the code I showed is a simple example.